# Import a Play Framework project to IntelliJ 14.1.5 Error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

#### Problem:

**IntelliJ** is not letting me **import** a **play framework project**. It just displays **errors** when I try to open project using **SBT**.

Its really simple what I want to do, but I haven't used any of these tools and I'm a bit lost at how to fix this.

I just want to create a **Play framework project**, and edit it in **IntelliJ** as shown on multiple tutorials on youtube.

Below I have provided some info about how I have tried to make it work to "help you help me".

I really hope there is some easy solution that I fail to see!

#### Background info:

I have downloaded and installed **IntelliJ 14.1.5 Community Edition** and the latest avtivator from Play Framework - **Activator 1.3.6** and **Play 2.4.3**

Note: I also downloaded the latest java jdk, **1.8.0_65** and added both java and activator to path - I'm using **Windows 8**. I have also downloaded the latest plugin of **Scala** inside **IntelliJ**

Then I opened **cmd** and typed "**activator ui**" and opened browser at localhost:8888 as instructed in tutorials. I managed to create a "**play-java-intro**" project. So far, so good.

After this I have tried a few different approaches.

**NOTE: I have clicked "Invalidate cache / restart" each time I try something new**

#### First try

I tried to **Open project** after I had created the project through activator. I selected root directory of the project and selected SDK **jdk 1.7** (have tried with 1.8 aswell).

I got the error

> Error while importing SBT project: ... at
>   sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70) at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65) at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24) at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65) at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48) at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32) at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24) at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53) at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28) at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109) at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129) at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109) at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36) at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117) at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19) at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44) at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20) at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) [error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 [error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Inside the log file:

> [info] Loading project definition from C:\play-java-intro\project
>   [info] Set current project to play-java-intro (in build file:/C:/play-java-intro/)
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:535)
>       at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157)
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$.com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load(SbtWeb.scala:549)
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
>       at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
>       at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
>       at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:319)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:484)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
>       at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
>       at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
>       at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
>       at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
>       at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
>       at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
>       at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
>       at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
>       at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
>   [error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>   [error] Use 'last' for the full log.

I have tried to search what this means, but the answers I find on google wont apply to my problem.

I have tried to select and deselect all of the options within SBT - **Use auto-import**, **Download sources and docs** etc.. But still the same error message.

#### Second try

Similar to first try, but I clicked "**Create IntelliJ project**" inside activator at localhost:8888 and then tried to import the project the same method as **First try**.

#### Third try

**Open project** and select the root directory, and I managed to import the project somewhat, but its moved project files to "project backup" and I got lots of warnings saying its based on a outdated version. Didn't quite understand this.

#### Fourth try

**Create project from existing sources** after creating the project at **activator**, and I got the project imported without warnings.

But when I open **Application.java** (or *any* other file for that matter), everything inside that file gets red underlined with a error saying similar to "**Cannot resolve symbol 'Result'**" and I cant compile anything.

I have tried to open modules and click **+** and add Scala as a module, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

---

I really hope there is someone out there that can help me as this should be a fairly easy thing to install IntelliJ + Play framework.

Comment: Did not you forget to enable scala plugin ? You can download it but leave it disabled, so just check. This is a good guide with screens: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that even if IntelliJ is set to use JDK8, the SBT process is using JDK7 (you can confirm that looking at it with a tool like `JVisualVM`). Not sure what their logic is to pick up SBT's JVM, but you can force it when you import the projet:

[image]

This solved it for me with this version of Idea:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights24

> Play 2.4 now requires JDK 8

So you definitely must use only JDK 8.

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Means that you try to open project that was compiled with JDK 8 but your settings in IDE is JDK 7 (or less)

My proposition - check twice if you really use JDK8 in the intelliJ

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!
I have typed javac -version in "cmd" and it says "1.8.0_65" also, I have tried to set SDK to 1.8 in IntelliJ, still same result, should I try to delete 1.7 from sdk in IntelliJ?

Comment: no - you need to select tcorrect version in the project as I know

Comment: @user2621292 did you get it working? I have the same problem. Selected JSK 8 for IntelliJ and for the project, but I still get the same error when importing